# Embedding google sheet cells that can be sorted by viewers

Tags: html, iframe, google-sheets, embed

I'd like embed a google sheet to my HTML website that would **show only cells with data** (no header, row numbering, letter-named columns, border etc.) and it **could be filtered by the viewers**. Viewers could temporarily filter the data but it shouldn't change the original filtering.

I have google sheet that has multiple columns with title and data below. I've filtered data (including title) using google sheets 'filter' option.
I'm aware that there's a way to embed sortable google sheet if I use share link that allows viewing or editing. But when I am using that edit or view link, I cannot use almost any [url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446449/google-sheet-embed-url-documentation).

- *Example edit/view link:* `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheet-key}/edit?usp=sharing`
- Best try so far is using url parameter &rm=minimal but it still shows other sheets, numbered rows and letter-named columns

I can use **url parameters** on link that I get from *`File -> Publish to the web -> Embed`*. Here's the link:

```
< iframe frameborder="0" height="440" scrolling="no" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheet-key}/pubhtml?gid=0&amp;single=true&amp;range=A1:N20&amp;widget=false&amp;chrome=false&amp;headers=false" style="float: left;" width="761"></iframe >
```

**=>** I get visually **just what I want**: a clean spreasheet embedded containing only data. But now it **can't be filtered**.

Here's best iframe so far (sortable but not clean):

```
< iframe height="440" frameBorder="0" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheet-key}/edit?usp=sharing&rm=minimal" width="761"></iframe >
```

**Is there a way to show only data cells and still allow sorting?**

Comment: Would this be a better fit in Web Apps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The filter/sort functionality gets lost when embedding a google sheet with html; same is true when freezing rows/columns. Google has not solved this yet, although it has been requested for years. It is possible to do this when embedding via Excel Online though, but that one is a bit slow.

Comment: So far this seems to be the answer. Hope this feature will appear in near future.

Comment: Tail of OP's statement would indicate that it is possible, but not in the clean way he desires.  May want to edit answer.

Comment: ~2.5 years later... same problem. =(

Comment: and another 1.5 years. same proble

Comment: There is a web service called Awesome Tables, which provides, among other things, this feature, AFAIK. You can even add filtering. It is paid after a given amount of rows / sheets (not sure), though.

Comment: @LucasLima can you tell if that is working? have you experienced with it? can you send a link?

Comment: Last I checked, it was working normally. I don't have experience with it, though - you can find it at https://awesome-table.com/. It should be pretty straight forward to use, given it has an interface quite similar to that found on GSuite apps.