# Render partial google spreadsheet on web app google apps script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I've intended make google spread sheet as a shared web site using freezed row. because on a shared web site, I couldn't fix columns and rows at all.
finally I noticed It may be possible to make successively if i use web app at google apps script as partial rendering.(as using html or javascript)

but I couldn't invoke partial google spread sheet which was setted range. when I did this I could see

> "It couldn't be showed".

but strangely when I didn't add range, It showed well. But It's not what I want.
(I got the information from here : https://www.steegle.com/google-sites/how-to/insert-websites-apps-scripts-and-gadgets/embed-google-sheet-range)

This is the applicable range that I want to fix on a website as using google apps script and web app.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L-NvkrbmiDk2nT7bUTRalrgON6K5zEFYZMu362GVNnE/htmlembed?single=true&gid=1680391550&range=A1:AI7&widget=false&chrome=false&headers=false

And this is all part of the document.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQZBVb3b0HgvmLSJBXpp57NkZTaa5Zn_HTQGwkenlhI_vLxmgxN_jwUY_TbLLCszyqIF2Ht-1qNf37o/pubhtml?gid=1680391550&single=true

I published document to be able to be showed to all user accessing the web app(viewing permission) on google spread sheet and web app.

I'd appreciate it if you could let me know about whatever you know, how to resolve this problem from A to Z. I want to know how to fix partial google spread sheet which was invoked as url on html page on web app from google apps script. or the way how to invoke partial google spread sheet on web app from google apps script.
thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653100/

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the desired output?

Comment: @Iamblichus
hello. What I want to do is to fix header panes(ranged rows and columns from google spread sheet) in a web page. cells from another range would be able to scroll.

Comment: @lamblichus
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbykYeLsNwgybxlr4jv9V4jqW0WfpHxlqdaxBy_1fLfnro5SacE/exec

so I tried to put in embadded script by iframe, but it isn't still working.
As a result I want to put ranged two part of google spread sheet in the web page (google web app from google apps script), and want to fix the above part and to scroll the other part.

Comment: @Iamblichus I'd appreciate it if you could let me know!

Comment: Looks like rows cannot be frozen on published sheets: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/10058220. But since you're using Apps Script, you could deploy a web app that will (1) retrieve the data in the spreadsheet, (2) add this data to an HTML table, and (3) fix the table top rows with the help of CSS/JS. Do you think that could be a valid workaround for you? If that's the case, I'd consider posting an answer.

Comment: @Iamblichus thank you for your answer. Yea you're right. I've also seen the posting before, but I couldn't resolve this yet. If It is possible to make with google apps script, I'd want to ask you letting me know how to resolve it. I think what you said would be nice workaround for me. I'd appreciate it if you could let me know how to resolve this as using google apps script and CSS/JS. I'm so thankful that you've considered to reslove this together.

Comment: Considering that your spreadsheet contains several merged cells, and considering all the formatting that would need to be done to emulate your spreadsheet format, the workaround I suggested would not be so trivial, I'm not sure this would be the best workaround. In this case, if you don't have problems making your spreadsheet public (shared with `Anyone with the link`), I think the way to go could be to embed the spreadsheet itself, and not its published version. This way, the spreadsheet would be seen as it is, with the frozen rows on top. What do you think of that?

Comment: @Iamblichus  Even if it is not so trivial, If It's okay, I'd choose that way since It's in need of mobile usability and convenience. What I want to make is a attendance sheet that anyone can use easily somehow. In the latter case, when I clicked the link(shared with anyone with the link, spreadsheet itself) on mobile I couldn't see the forezen rows on top. and in my opinion, there is some scope to cause confusion if the spreadsheet UI like rows' number and columns' number is shown.
So I preferably wish to make it as the former. I hope it wouldn't be a hassle for you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

Rows cannot be frozen on published sheets: see [How can I freeze cols/rows in a public shared table?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/10058220).

#### Workaround #1. Embed spreadsheet itself:

Instead of [publishing the file to the web](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965) and embedding this published version (URL containing `/pubhtml`), you could embed the spreadsheet itself, if you don't have problems making this spreadsheet public (shared with `Anyone with the link`). This way, the spreadsheet would be seen as it is, with the frozen rows on top.

You mentioned in comments, though, that you have noticed that the frozen rows cannot be seen correctly on your mobile device, and this causes this workaround not to be appropriate for your situation.

#### Workaround #2. Build HTML table:

A rather less direct and more laborious workaround could be to do the following (I'll just give some broad pointers and include references for you to investigate further):

- Retrieve the data from the sheet via [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) and [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues). Since headers should be frozen (they should have separate styling), I'd suggest to retrieve the headers and the rest of the data separately.
- Using this data, create an [HTML template](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) to create a dynamically created [HTML table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).
- When retrieving the data, you should take into account that some cells are merged. You should get the information about which cells are merged and with which ones, and use that information when creating the HTML table. [Range.isPartOfMerge()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#ispartofmerge) can be used to check whether cells are merged (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33018340) for more pointers about the subject). You should in its turn merge the corresponding table cells, for example, using the `colspan` attribute from [td element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td). See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4342336).
- You should use [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) or similar, to effectively freeze the headers. There are many questions on StackOverflow that tackle this issue. See [Freezing/Fixing the Top Header Row of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15307135) or [Freeze the top row for an html table only (Fixed Table Header Scrolling)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8423768) for starters.

#### Code sample:

Here I attach the code to retrieve the data from the sheet and use it to create a dynamic table (the styling features –frozen rows, general formatting– and the issue with the merged cells are not included –if you have problems with these issues, I'd suggest you to post questions separately about these–):

> Code.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index").evaluate();
}

function getHeaders() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("출석부");
  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, 7, sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
}

function getBody() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("출석부");
  const firstRow = 8;
  const numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1;
  return sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
}
```

> index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <? const headers = getHeaders();
        for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) { ?>
          <tr>
            <? for (let j = 0; j < headers[0].length; j++) { ?>
            <th><?= headers[i][j] ?></th>
            <? } ?>
        <? } ?>
      </thead>      
      <tbody>
        <? const body = getBody(); 
        for (let k = 0; k < body.length; k++) { ?>
          <tr>
            <? for (let l = 0; l < body[0].length; l++) { ?>
            <td><?= body[k][l] ?></td>
            <? } ?>
        <? } ?>     
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Reference:

- [How can I freeze cols/rows in a public shared table?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/10058220)
- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was so amazing. Thank you once again for everything you've done.

Comment: @김범석 You're welcome! I hope this can help you reaching your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can place it as iframe in your html and then add a lot of parameters to format it the way you want. Many resources online for the parameters.

```
<span><br><iframe src="DOCSURL/pubhtml?gid=37486499&amp;single=true&single=true&range=A2&amp;widget=false&amp;chrome=false&amp;headers=false" height="50" ></iframe> </span>
<br>
```

That basically it gives me a single cell.
Besides the parameters you can apply css to your iframe.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but sadly It doesn't work....TT

Comment: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbykYeLsNwgybxlr4jv9V4jqW0WfpHxlqdaxBy_1fLfnro5SacE/exec
This is the result and even I can't see it.

Comment: Dude you need to change the gid with your. aka gid=37486499 with gid=1680391550. Let me know, and if it works consider marking the answer as correct. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The Apps Script HTML table rendering solution is good and well-explained with examples. However it's very slow for thousands of rows.

A way to address this may be to instead use a Javacsript library on the client that asynchronously retrieves the data and loads it into the page.

##### OPTION: Get a filtered CSV using the /gviz API

use a frontend/backend model where you write an HTML/JS page that calls the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) to return only the correct rows via CSV. The URL will look like `https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_KEY/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet=Sheet1&tq=select%A%2C%20sum(B)%20group%20by%20A`

##### OPTION: Download the entire sheet as CSV into the page

And filter with Javascript `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET_KEY/export?format=csv&id=KEY&gid=SHEET_ID` and render it.

##### OPTION: Use Apps Script to extract rows and return a filtered CSV

Use the Apps Script endpoint as a "CSV API" to download filtered sets of data to the page.