# Force desktop view in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, iframe, query-string, querystringparameter

is there a way to set the parameters in spreadsheet to force the user agent to desktop mode? i have used the ?fd=true and overridemobile=true but still its not working.

```
<header>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024"> 
</header>   
<div class="ads" style="auto; width: 99%; height: 640px; overflow: hidden;">
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1frhC32sdgAYq7ZbqNdCQHeziwpolY8CLcVFFBrXBQqA/edit?rm=minimal&amp;fd=true#gid=10012724" height="750" width="670" style="border: none; margin-left:-44px; margin-top:-23px; "></iframe>
</div>
```

thank you for response

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Google sheet embed URL documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23446449/1595451)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, what is the result of what you have so far and why is that not working for you? I suspect that due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) the iframe will be quite limited.

Comment: i want to force the mobile devices to behave like they are using desktop. I've already used viewport at the meta but the only the views are changed into desktop mode. The iframe is still unresponsive like in desktop