# URL to Google Sheet Cell with New Cell Data

Tags: google-sheets

I'm hopeful that some of you Google Sheets experts can confirm something for me. A URL to a Google Sheets cell or range is possible. Here is an example of a URL to a cell, D2:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/KEY/edit#gid=0&range=D2

**What I'd like to do is include data to be placed in that cell using a URL.** This discussion was useful, as it provided many of the available options: [Google sheet embed URL documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446449/google-sheet-embed-url-documentation) . The following were incorporated into the URL in an attempt to put data in the cell: start and q. However, they did not work. **Could you experts please confirm that cell data can not be incorporated into the URL?**

By the way, this question comes out of an attempt to build a small inventory system within Google Sheets using QR codes. The QR codes would be linked back to a cell in Google Sheets where the QR code (URL link to the cell with item number included) would place the item number into that cell. With the item number in that cell, the item details would be shown.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see also: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130655/186471

Comment: Whenever possible, please include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue so people can better understand how you are implementing this and help by providing a definitive answer or a workaround.

Comment: Hi Yancy, here are some specific examples attempted:
 
[link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/KEY/edit#gid=0&range=D1
- goes to the cell no problem
  
 
[link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/KEY/edit#gid=0&range=D1&start=1234 
- &start=1234 added, goes to the cell, but does not edit it
  
 
[link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/KEY/edit#gid=0&range=D1&q=1234 
- &q=1234 added, goes to the cell, but does not edit it
   
 
So my question is, does Google have a parameter that allows me to edit the cell through a URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through extensive documentation research and through several similar questions on this site:

This is not a Google Sheets built-in feature. Google does not provide any official documentation that proves the contrary.

Looking into an alternative option I found this Google Sheets [API endpoint](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) you can use to add values to an specific cell as shown below:

[image]

Aside from the above, you could submit a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/)

Comment: Yancy Melany, thank you very much for confirming what I suspected. Your research, as well as an alternative solution, is very impressive.  Much appreciated! I will submit a feature request. Great idea. Thanks again.

Comment: Just attempted to submit a feature request. Sadly, I don't have the credentials for that link. Will look for another path to request this feature.

Comment: You are welcome, also, please try this [other link](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Comment: Thanks Yancy. That site worked well. A feature request was submitted this morning. You've been very helpful. THANKS!