# How to embed google sheets in HTML - only show the last few rows

Tags: html, google-sheets

I am embedding a google sheet into html. I can use `&range=A1:C10` argument to show just a selected region.

```html
    <iframe src="link_to_sheets&range=A3:C10" ></iframe>
```

Is there a way to just show the last 10 rows of the file?

Comment: None of what I can find on the matter (including a quite comprehensive list of possible parameters such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/23446449/1427878), suggests that was possible.